# Прозрачность Фона

Tags: android

У меня LinearLayout и два текста! У Линеар фон должен быть прозрачно белым, а тексты у них свой цвет и они не должны менятся! Но проблема в том, что когда фон Лэйоута делаю прозрачным то и тексты становятся прозрачными...

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:alpha="0.2">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle1"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/title1"
            android:textColor="@color/titleEnableColor" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/title2"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Comment: [Что делать когда кто-то ответил на мой вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: вы прозрачным делаете не фон, а весь LinearLayout, вместе с его содержимым.

Comment: Если один из предложенных ответов решил заявленную в вопросе проблему, то хорошим тоном считается проголосовать за него и отметить его "верным".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alpha канал можете указать в background color. В вашем случае 20% это #14. Должно выглядеть так:

```
android:background="#14ffffff"
```

Прозрачность фона 20%, фон белый

Попробуйте.

Comment: Альфа идет первым значением - #aarrggbb и в HEX - десятичное 20 будет #14

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Помогло!!!

Comment: @pavlofff, все верно, спасибо за правку